# Index.php doesn't show my new modify in home page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this index.php:

```
<?php
    //Getting Header
    get_header();
?>

    <div><h1>DOG</h1></div>

<!-- This do this function -->
    <!-- Content section -->
    <div class="content-section module blog-page">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                $object_id = get_queried_object_id();

                //Getting Single Post Sidebar Position 
//yes
                $wc_sidebar_position_default = get_theme_mod("wc_blogsection_manage_sidebar");
                $wc_sidebar_position_special = get_post_meta($object_id, "wc_innerpage_sidebar_position", true);

                if($wc_sidebar_position_special == "left_sidebar"  || 
                   $wc_sidebar_position_special == "right_sidebar" || 
                   $wc_sidebar_position_special == "disable_sidebar") { 
                    $wc_sidebar_position = $wc_sidebar_position_special;
                } else { 
                    $wc_sidebar_position = $wc_sidebar_position_default;
                }

                switch($wc_sidebar_position) { 
                    case "left_sidebar":
                        //left sidebar
                        get_sidebar();
                        //Getting posts sides
                        get_template_part('template-parts/post-type/blog');
                    break;

                    case "right_sidebar":
                        //Getting posts sides
                        get_template_part('template-parts/post-type/blog');
                        //Right Sidebar
                        get_sidebar();
                    break;

                    case "disable_sidebar":
                        //Getting posts sides
                        get_template_part('template-parts/post-type/blog'); 
                    break;

                    default:
                        //Getting posts sides
                        get_template_part('template-parts/post-type/blog');
                        //Right Sidebar
                        get_sidebar();
                }//Ends Switch
            ?>
        </div><!-- Row Ends /-->
    </div>
    <!-- Content Section Ends /-->

<?php
    //Getting Footer
    get_footer();
```

I want read "DOG" in my page after header but I don't read anything when I reload the page and I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `<div><h1>DOG</h1></div>` inside of the div `<div class="content-section module blog-page">` for so it looks like this:

```
<div class="content-section module blog-page">
<div><h1>DOG</h1></div>
...
```

Is it visible now?

Comment: Can you tell me what theme you are using? And what page are you looking at? There are various files for displaying different page types, so it's hard with so little info

Answer (score 0):

Your home page may not be served up by index.php. There could be several other possible template files that would display instead.

For example, if your theme has a front-page.php, that would be the file you'd want to edit. Or, if the homepage is running as a page with a custom page template, you might be looking for something like template-home.php. Tough to say exactly without seeing the site / code, just like a previous commenter said..